# Describe formally the following model

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

So I came across this exercise in my book.

> a) Let $U$ be any random variable and $V$ be any other nonnegative
>   random variable. Show that 
>                $$F_{U+V}(t) \le F_U(t)\ for\ every \ t $$
>
> b)Describe formally the following model. Two groups of $n_1$ and $n_2$
>   individuals, respectively, are sampled at random from a very large
>   population. Each member of the second (treatment) group is
>   administered the same dose of a certain drug believed to lower blood
>   pressure and the blood pressure is measured after 1 hour. Each member
>   of the first (control) group is administered an equal dose of placebo
>   and then has the blood pressure measured after 1 hour. It is known
>   that the drug either has no effect or lowers blood pressure, but the
>   distribution of blood pressure in the population sampled before and
>   after administration of the drug is quite unknown.

---

*So for the* **a)** *I showed that* $F_U(t)-F_{U+V}(t)\ge0$ *which led me to* $\int_{t-v}^tf_U(t)dt \ge0$ *as f is assumed to be a legitimate PDF hence* $F_{U+V}(t) \le F_U(t)\ for\ every \ t $

$X_i$: Blood Pressure from the ith individual,

$Y_i$: Response to the medication on the ith individual

*For* **b)** I set a model $Y_i$ being the response from $X_i-\Delta$ with $i=0,1,2,...,n_1$

and $Y'_i$ being the response from placebo on $X_i$ with $i=0,1,2,...,n_2$

I could do the same thing as **a)** but I don't know if I should assume the $X's$ to be normal with mean  $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ which are unknowns.

**Does anyone know how to go about that?
Any input will be greatly appreciated**.

Comment: You might find it instructive to prove part (a) without introducing the (limiting and unnecessary) assumption that $U$ has a density.  As far as (b) goes, a similar observation holds: don't introduce assumptions that weren't made in the problem statement.

Comment: I couldn't prove without doing so. Do you have tips? I know from googling about Stochastic ordering but couldn't use anything from it.

Comment: One proof of (a) observes that since $V\ge 0,$ the condition $U+V\le t$ implies (via the axioms of ordering) that $U\le t.$ An axiom of probability immediately tells us that $$F_{U+V}(t)=\Pr(U+V\le t)\le \Pr(U\le t)=F_U(t),$$ *QED.*

Comment: I would be able to cross off this exercise now. I really appreciated this response, thank you ! @whuber